Command line to tell if monitor is off in wayland?
I used to do this in a bash script to tell if a monitor was on or off ("off" meaning off, or what happens after xset dpms force off is run):
xset q | grep "Monitor is Off"
...what is an equivalent under Wayland? I found ddccontrol -p on another answer, and it seems like it would work but it is far too slow (takes multiple seconds to return).
I'm using kscreen-doctor --dpms off to turn the screens off.

See my answer using ddcutil, which is also slow but you can first find the monitor's i2c bus, then later directly address it more quickly. The same is probably true for ddccontrol: dont use -p, use the found bus.

Thanks @meuh -- that's helpful but it doesn't seem to work for me. I tried with all three monitors I have and none of them change state when slept. For the record, I'm using "kscreen-doctor --dpms off" to turn the screens off. ddcutil always returns "DPM: On,  DPMS: Off (sl=0x01)" regardless of the state.

Same results with ddccontrol dev:/dev/i2c-7 -r 0xd6 (also tried with 0xe1 "Power control" -- also no change.)

You could dump all the vcp code values with the monitor on and then off to see if there are any differences. It's very slow with a timeout on each unsupported code, but possibly worth a try: ddcutil --bus xxx probe

Thanks! -- it was PEBCAK -- I wasn't waiting long enough. Takes 8-10 seconds before DPM: Off happens.

Temporary answer until/unless someone has a better solution (thanks to @meuh for this): use ddcutil (ubuntu package ddcutil) find the i2c bus of a monitor and query it.
You can use vcp code 0x6d and look for "DPM: Off" but on my monitors it takes 8-10 seconds after "kscreen-doctor --dpms off" for that state to actually change.
However you can also use code 0x60 ("Input Source") and look for it to change to "Invalid value (sl=0x00)" which happens immediately when the screen is turned off.
I filed a bug against kscreen-doctor so that KDE users might have a more convenient way to do this.
Process:
Find the i2c bus with dcutil (here it reveals bus 7 for a monitor):
$ ddcutil detect
...
Display 3
   I2C bus:  /dev/i2c-7
...

Query the DPM state with ddcutil:
$ ddcutil --bus 7 getvcp 0xd6
VCP code 0xd6 (Power mode                    ): DPM: On,  DPMS: Off (sl=0x01)

("DPM: On" means the monitor is on, "DPM: Off" means it is off.)
...but that takes 8-10 seconds, so I do this instead:
$ ddcutil --bus 7 getvcp 0x60
VCP code 0x60 (Input Source                  ): DVI-1 (sl=0x03)

I see "DVI-1" (your monitor may vary) and when off it shows:
$ ddcutil --bus 7 getvcp 0x60
VCP code 0x60 (Input Source                  ): Invalid value (sl=0x00)

...I assume "Invalid value" will appear if the monitor is disconnected or switched off as well, but I haven't tested.
NOTE: for me sometimes ddcutil returns with an error as the screen is sleeping or waking up, so any scripts using this method should be aware of that.
